# Protractor, code inside promise function is not never executed

Tags: javascript, selenium, promise, protractor

I'm using protractor and during the execution I noticed that the promises are not performed inside the function. Can anyone help me?

```
Then('I want to see three accordion items with the related links', function () {
var accordion = element.all(by.css('.accordion.element'));
browser.driver.wait(accordion.count().then(function(agg){      
browser.pause('il numero da verificare porca di quella : ', agg); 
console.log('il numero è:', agg);   //NON VIENE STAMPATO IL LOG
//expect(number).to.equal(3);
}));
});
```

Comment: What is actual result and what is expected result? Everything looks fine for me. See the documentation/: http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.pause

Comment: Hi @Kacper, thank you for your answer. I want to see the console.log works, but at the moment when I launch the test, it is not showed and the test pass, like the code inside the function is not executed. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: IMO it stops due to `browser.pause()`. Try to comment that line and run the test again.